# How are you supposed to handle the need to call the In-App review API

Tags: android

I'm looking at the new [In-App review API](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review/kotlin-java) and one thing I can't quite understand is how to handle the need for the review request.

The review flow's `OnCompleteListener` doesn't give you any indication on whether the user submitted a review or whether the dialog was shown at all, so how am I supposed to know whether I should prompt the user again at a later date? If the user submitted a review I certainly wont prompt them again. If the dialog wasn't shown at all, it would make sense to ask again at a later date, or perhaps they clicked the "not now" button, which does indicate to the user that they might be asked again later. There is some mention of a quota in the documentation but I have no idea how it works and how I should manage it.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, you should trigger the API every time you bring some value to the user (for example if the user finishes a level in a game). The API itself will decide how often it will be shown to the user, if they press "Not now". You don't have to care about it.

Comment: Hmm but the documentation also says "Do not prompt the user excessively for a review", which is kind of confusing if the API decides when to show the prompt.